# Mosaic and merge rasters iteratively using R raster package

Tags: raster, r, merge, mosaic

I have a list of RasterStack objects. Some of them overlap and some of them do not. I need to merge all the files into a single RasterStack object to finally export it as a GeoTiff file.

My approach is to go through the list of RasterStack objects called `rstack_list` and evaluate and apply `raster::mosaic` (if they overlap) and `raster::merge` (if they do not overlap). So it would be something like this:

```
library(raster)

r <- rstack_list[[1]]
for(i in 2:length(rstack_list)){
  if(extent(i) ¿INTERSECT? extent(r) == TRUE){
    r <- raster::mosaic(r, i, fun=mean)
  }else{
    r <- raster::merge(r, i)
  }
}
```

However I don't know how to solve the *¿INTERSECT?* conditional.

Is there a more direct and properly way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `intersect()` function from the `raster` package. The function will not return a condition rather it would return a new raster that overlaps from the two rasters. If it returns null the rasters don't overlap.

```
for(i in 2:length(rstack_list)){
  if(!is.null(intersect(rstack_list[[i]],r))){
    r <- raster::mosaic(r, rstack_list[[i]], fun=mean)
  }
  else{
   r <- raster::merge(r, rstack_list[[i]])
  }
  }
```

*N.B:* You used `i` in 'extent()' but it will run in an error since `i` is only the index. You have to access the rasters from the `raster_stacklist`. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

The raster packages is being replaced by terra (same developer) so, migrating is rather important before raster is depreciated (and it is notably faster). There are no longer separate classes for single or multi band rasters, it is simply a SpatRaster class read using `terra::rast`.

There is also no need to iterate, you can create a raster collection (list) and apply `merge` or `mosaic` on that object. Something along the lines of: 1) create list object of rasters in a directory, 2) create a collection and 3) pass to `terra::mosaic`.

```
f <- lapply(list.files(wd, "tif$", full.names = TRUE),
            terra::rast)
  f <- sprc(f)
    f.mosaic <- mosaic(f, fun="mean")
```